# Install Ubuntu with BTRFS and more subvolumes

Tags: server, btrfs

I want to install an Ubuntu Server with a `btrfs` filesystem (in a RAID1 way).

The problem is that I can't see the option in the installer to make more subvolumes. The installer creates two by default: `@` and `@home`, and I want to separate also `@var`, `@tmp`, ...

Is there any option to do this? Maybe with the shell... but I think the installer doesn't understand the subvolumes feature of `btrfs`, so you can't mount each partition in each subvolume...

Answer (score 3):

This should be easy enough to change after you have finished your initial install.

- One neat way is to take two snapshots of `@`, calling them `@var` and `@tmp`.
- Then delete everything in `@var` except for `@var/var`, them move the contents of `@var/var/*` up to `@var/*` and delete `@var/var`.  Same for `@tmp/tmp/`.
- Then modify `/etc/fstab` with the new subvolume mount points for `/var` and `/tmp`.
- Reboot.
- Finally (I'm not so sure about this last bit) you should be able to delete the original contents of `@/var` and `@/tmp` by mounting the subvolume `@` under `/mnt` (so the same subvolume is mounted twice, once as `/` and once as `/mnt`) and deleting `/mnt/var` and `/mnt/tmp`.

Comment: Some documentation about working with snapshots in Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/btrfs#How_to_work_with_snaphots_in_Ubuntu.27s_layout

Answer (score 3):

You're right, the installer is not aware of BTRFS subvolumes, and this is still the case for 18.04.

Using a separate subvolume for `/var/log/` allows to restore a snapshot of `/` without loosing the logs.

- Do the server setup as usual, at the *Finish installation* step, select **Go Back** and **Execute a shell**.
- List all your target file systems:

  ```
  mount | grep target

  /dev/md-0 on /target type btrfs (rw,noatime,space_cache,subvolid=257,subvol=/@)
  /dev/md-0 on /target/home type btrfs (rw,noatime,space_cache,subvolid=258,subvol=/@home)
  proc on /target/proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
  devtmpfs on /target/dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=475608k,nr_inodes=118902,mode=755)
  ```
- Take a note of the btrfs device, in this example `/dev/dm-0`.
- Now un-mount all of your mounted file systems.

  ```
  umount /target/dev
  umount /target/proc
  umount /target/boot/efi
  umount /target/home
  umount /target/
  ```
- Mount your **flat** btrfs filesystem :

  ```
  cd /tmp
  mkdir work
  mount /dev/dm-0 work
  cd work
  ```
- Verify the mount is correct (should show `@` and `@home`):

  ```
  ls 

  @ @home
  ```
- Create your additional subvolumes (`@tmp`, `@var`, `@var-log`)

  ```
  btrfs subvolume create @tmp
  btrfs subvolume create @var
  btrfs subvolume create @var-log
  ```
- Move the data

  ```
  mv @/var/log/* @var-log/
  mv @/var/* @var/

  # Remove data from tmp
  rm @/tmp/* @/tmp/.*

  # For 18.04, remove the swapfile since it won't work on btrfs
  rm @/swapfile
  ```
- Add the new subvolumes to fstab, the device part may be different than the previous mount command, copy the device part from the already existing mount points.

  ```
  ...
  /dev/mapper/root-root /               btrfs   noatime,subvol=@ 0       1
  /dev/mapper/root-root /home           btrfs   noatime,subvol=@home 0       2
  /dev/mapper/root-root /var            btrfs   noatime,subvol=@var 0       2
  /dev/mapper/root-root /var/log        btrfs   noatime,subvol=@var-log 0       2
  ```
- Unmount

  ```
  cd /tmp
  umount work
  sync
  ```
- `exit`, then **Finish the installation**
- Install and configure [snapper](http://snapper.io), a great tool for automatizing snapshots.